# Добавление атрибута после двойного клика

Tags: javascript, jquery

У пользователя есть возможность редактировать текст. Я нашел полезный атрибут `contenteditable`, однако по условию мне нужно сделать так, что бы только после двойного клика появлялась возможность редактировать текст. Я то сделал так что это все работает, но высвечивается "поле ввода" не сразу, а только после третьего щелка. То есть как бы, за первые два курсор мыши выделяет ту область куда пользователь кликнул, а на третьем оно уже дает возможность редактировать. Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить эту ошибку!

JS

```
$("span").dblclick(function(){
   document.getElementById(this.id).setAttribute("contenteditable", "true");
});
```

HTML

```
<span id="elementId">klick on me twice</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
$("span").dblclick(function(){
   $(this).attr("contenteditable", "true");
   console.log(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="elementId">klick on me twice</span>
```